# AWS Route53 to external DNS service A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes

I have brought `example.com` from one of address sellers.

On AWS I have Application Load Balancer.
I have created Route53 hosted zone and added this load balancer as A record alias:

[image]

How should I receive this records *constant* IP address to link my external DNS A record to this Route53?

I can't put CNAME to `example.com`, only sub-domain. When adding IP from `Test Record Set` IP list, they are changing from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to switch to using a Network Load balancer to get a consistent IP address.

> Static IP support
>
> Network Load Balancer automatically provides a **static IP per Availability Zone (subnet)** that can be used by applications as the front-end IP of the load balancer.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details

Also you'll want to switch to an ALIAS instead of an A record.

> Queries to Alias records that are mapped to Elastic Load Balancers,
>   Amazon CloudFront distributions, AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments,
>   and Amazon S3 website buckets are free
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/